# Layout inspector not working, something couldn't be downloaded from maven

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose, layout-inspector

I have layout inspector server installed, mavencentral in build.gradle(project) and a device running API 33. I can only see a mirror of my app running below the message, nothing in the component tree or under attributes.

[image: Error]